# How to customize the general product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to locate the specific file to change the general product layout/look in WooCommerce. Can't find documentation on this anywhere. Which files I have to edit to to be able to edit the product image, price, title, and "Buy Now" button placement and look. I know how to override the default WooCommerce templates so I'm looking for the specific file to edit to make these changes.

Here's where I'm at: [Regular WooCommerce Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUJGD.png)

This is what I'm trying to achieve: [Ideal Product Look + Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axZxn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You customize that by [developing a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/).

Ideally you want to [create a wordpress child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

If you find that you need to go beyond style modifications for the woocommerce pages you may need to copy the woocommerce templates and modify them.

You have to copy all the files from woocoomerce/templates/ to yourtheme/woocommerce/.

If theme development is beyond your understanding, you might want to look at a marketplace like Themeforest, find something close to what you want and either figure out or pay someone a fee to tweak it for you.

Comment: I am using a child theme of a blank starter WooCommerce theme and trying to find the specific PHP file in the WooCommerce templates to override so that I can edit the placement and style of the product title, image, price, "Buy Now" button. There are many files associated with products, however I am just looking for the file(s) which effect the regular default product layouts and styles.

Answer (score 0):

You should read all about Woocommerce hooks. We can change the layout, add and remove extra things on the product page, shop page and anywhere as required.

Woocommerce provides rich lists hooks and filters that are very helpful.

Here is the link to:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: ^^ Thanks gonna look into this, probably is what I was looking for.